# please why my spring boot not render http view and i got result on json format

Tags: spring-boot, web-applications

I useing ModuleAndView and thymleaf to display a list and I'm trying to render it through a controller.
i m successfully get result with Json Format however on browser i get This massage " site can’t be reached."

- Thymleaf Dependency added
  -web starter added
  resullt json format on psotman
  thymleaf properties added

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Conference Applications</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container=5">
    <h2>Session List </h2>


    <h2>
         
    
    </h2>

        <hr/>
    <a th:href="@{/session-form}" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Add Session</a>

        <table class="table table-header table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Session Id </th>
                <th>  name </th>
                <th> description</th>
                <th> length</th>

                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
                        integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
                        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                        integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V"
                        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <tr th:each = "se: ${sessions}">
            <td th:text="${se.getSession_id()}"></td>
            <td th:text="${se.getSession_name()}"></td>
            <td th:text="${se.getSession_description()}"></td>
            <td th:text="${se.getSession_length()}"></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
package com.example.springboot.controller;

import com.example.springboot.model.Session;
import com.example.springboot.repositery.SessionRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class SessionController {
    @Autowired
    private SessionRepository sessionRepository;


    @GetMapping({"/show-session"})
    public ModelAndView showSession(){
        ModelAndView muv = new ModelAndView("show-session");
        List<Session> list = sessionRepository.findAll();
        muv.addObject("sessions", list);
        return muv;
    }

    @GetMapping("/session-form")
    public ModelAndView sessionsForm() {
        ModelAndView muv = new ModelAndView("session-form");
        Session session = new Session();
        muv.addObject("session", session);
        return muv;
    }


    @PostMapping({ "/save-session"} )
    public ModelAndView saveSession( @ModelAttribute  final Session session) {
        sessionRepository.saveAndFlush(session);
        return showSession();

    }

    @GetMapping("/sessions/{id}")
    public Session get(@PathVariable("id") Long  id) {
        return sessionRepository.getReferenceById(id);
    }




    @DeleteMapping(value ="/sessions/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        sessionRepository.deleteById(id);

    }

    @PutMapping(value ="/sessions/{id}")
    public Session update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Session session){
        Session existsession = sessionRepository.getReferenceById(id);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(session, existsession, "session_id");
        return sessionRepository.saveAndFlush(existsession);

    }




}
```

```html
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springBoot</name>
    <description>springBoot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you getting “result on JSON format” or are you getting “site can’t be reached?”

Comment: i get json format but no html format

Comment: i don't know why doesn't render webview . it's working on postman and i can see the page view ... no error with run debug ... i check pom, properties , even code i can not see error i used restcontroller and controller ..plese if u have recommendation

Comment: Please name the html files in your question. Please add application.properties/yml. Are your html files in resources/templates?

Comment: thanks john yes html files in resources/templates . the was the port was blocked from browser